# Vuex mutate state in module with function in other module

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have 2 modules in Vuex:

- Auth (auth.js)
- User (user.js)

In my User module I have the following action:

```
const actions = {
  [UPDATE_USER_ACCOUNT](context, payload) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      ESApiService.put("/api/user", payload)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          context.commit('[SET_AUTH]', data.data.user, { root: true })
          //context.commit(SET_USER_ACCOUNT, payload);
          resolve(data);
        })
        .catch(({ response }) => {
          context.commit(SET_ERROR, response);
        });
    });
  },
}
```

The current problem is that I get the following error: `[vuex] unknown mutation type: [SET_AUTH]`

I also tried: `context.commit('SET_AUTH', data.data.user, { root: true })` and getting this error: `[vuex] unknown mutation type: SET_AUTH`

SET_AUTH is been registered in: auth.js as following:

```
[SET_AUTH](state, user) {
  state.isAuthenticated = true;
  state.user = user;
  state.errors = {};
},
```

How to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using namespaces try with this:

```
commit('SET_AUTH', data.data.user, { root: true })
```

if your are using namespaces

```
commit('namespace/SET_AUTH', data.data.user, { root: true })
```